# Touch ID Passcode Integration in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, touch-id, passcode

I'm working on iOS app in which I need to integrate touch id and passcode, i googled and found many tutorials for touch id, I followed [this](http://www.appcoda.com/touch-id-api-ios8/) and done successfully. Every thing fine but on popup which is saying **Enter Password**
as shown in following pic [image: picture] i have few queries.

- Is it possible to use apple default passcode view as shown in lock screen?
- If Yes, then will apple allow to upload app onto appstore?

Looking for help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to hide password option try this..

```
var LocalAuthentication = LAContext()

LocalAuthentication.localizedFallbackTitle = ""  // Add this line
```

tutorial which you have mentioned is using only  Biometrics authentication with  `deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics` which Indicates that the device owner authenticated using Touch ID [refer this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lapolicy) .

If you want to authenticate with any of one (Touch id or passcode) , use `deviceOwnerAuthentication` instead.

replace

`[context .evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics ..`

with

```
[context .evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthentication  ..
```

Comment: I used and works fine, but I want to know is apple encourage to use this, and will apple allow to upload my app into appstore by using this ?

Comment: @Aleem, Yes, Appel will allow your app with this. because everything I have mentioned is in apple's public document...  refer these links for detail:  https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lacontext/1514183-localizedfallbacktitle  https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lapolicy

Comment: your provided link doesn't show me that apple will allow app to upload on appstore without any restriction but where I'm confuse is that we are accessing Apple default lock screen within app so could you provide me any hint ?

Comment: @Aleem we are not using apple's lock screen, we are using Authentication Method which apple has made public. (Its public API).  Apple never reject app for using Public and documented api. It rejects only when we try to use Private api - which is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

We can't use Apple's default lockscreen view inside our apps, However you can use [this library](https://github.com/abury/ABPadLockScreen) on github.

Comment: I would assume that having code resembling Apple's default lock screen in your app will get your app rejected.